# How do the for / while / print *things* work in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, syntax, while-loop

What i mean is, how is the syntax defined, i.e. how can i make my own constructs like these?

I realise in a lot of languages, things like this will be built into the compiler / spec, and so it's dealt with by the compiler (at least that how i understand it to work).

But with python, everything i've come across so far has been accessible to the programmer, and so you more or less have the freedom to do whatever you want.

How would i go about writing my own version of `for` or `while`? Is it even possible?

I don't have any actual application for this, so the answer to any WHY?! questions is just "because why not?" or "curiosity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a couple of options for creating your own syntax:

1. Write a higher-order function, like `map` or `reduce`.
2. Modify python at the C level. This is, as you might expect, *relatively* easy as compared with fiddling with many other languages. See this article for an example: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/30/python-internals-adding-a-new-statement-to-python/
3. Fake it using the debug facilities, or the encodings facility. See this code: http://entrian.com/goto/download.html and http://timhatch.com/projects/pybraces/
4. Use a preprocessor. Here's one project that tries to make this easy: http://www.fiber-space.de/langscape/doc/index.html
5. Use of the python facilities built in to achieve a similar effect (decorators, metaclasses, and the like).

Obviously, none of this is quite what you're looking for, but python, unlike smalltalk or lisp, isn't (necessarily) programmed in itself and guarantees to expose its own underlying execution and parsing mechanisms at runtime.

Comment: Thank you. You glorious stranger.

Comment: The `goto` project is fantastic.

Comment: @will You're welcome! Here's another project which hijacks the encodings feature: http://timhatch.com/projects/pybraces/

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't, not from within Python.  You can't add new syntax to the language.  (You'd have to modify the source code of Python itself to make your own custom version of Python.)

Note that the [iterator protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) allows you to define objects that can be used with `for` in a custom way, which covers a lot of the possible use cases of writing your own iteration syntax.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of the iterator protocol. So you're saying the syntax of flow control and such is all hard coded in and there's no way of overriding it (short of altering `python` to some bastardisation).

Answer (score 1):

You can't make equivalent constructs. `for`, `while`, `if` etc. are [*statements*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html), and they are built into the language with their own specific syntax. There are languages that *do* allow this sort of thing though (to some degree), such as [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org).

Answer (score 1):

`while`, `print`, `for` etc. are keywords. That means they are parsed by the python parser whilst reading the code, stripped any redundant characters and result in tokens. Afterwards a lexer takes those tokens as input and builds a program tree which is then excuted by the interpreter. Said so, those constructs are used only as syntactic sugar for underlying lexical machinery and as such are not visible from inside the code.

Comment: So what you're saying, is that if i wrote my own parser, and put it at the top of the main, then i could parse my own code, modify it in place, and then restart the code, and gain all the functionality i wish for? (that is if i were somewhat insane)

Comment: Nothing to do with being insane. A lot a languages exist, that as a first step convert the custom source into a source intelligible to another parser/lexer/interpreter/compiler and then run it on the target runtime.

Comment: Yes, you could write your own parser, lexer and  interpreter that would be defined by your very own grammar and then generate python code that would in turn be ran through pythons machinery, or you could directly output executable code. If you are interested in writing your simple interpreter, try bcnf converter tool - it is capable of generating a parser and lexer in java/c++/haskell given bcnf grammar. Also regarding Python - functions have a special `__code__` object that is used by python when executing the function - you could try to meddle with it for some fun results